# How can I write this conditional in fewer lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this code in my model:

```
percentage = 0
if self.date_of_birth.present?
  percentage += 15
end
if self.gender.present?
  percentage += 15
end
if self.relationship_status.present?
  percentage += 10
end
if self.language.present?
  percentage += 10
end
if self.qualification.present?
  percentage += 10
end
if self.interests.present?
  if self.interests.count >= 10
    percentage += 10
  else
    percentage += self.interests.count * 5
  end
end
```

But it does not look good. It is a lot of code for a small thing. I want to reduce the number of lines.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it inline, like this:

```
percentage += 15 if self.date_of_birth.present?
```

Instead of this:

```
if self.interests.count >= 10
    percentage += 10
else
    percentage += self.interests.count*5
end
```

You can use a ternary operator:

```
percentage += self.interests.count >= 10 ? 10 : self.interests.count*5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
percentage = [
  (15 if date_of_birth.present?),
  (15 if gender.present?),
  (10 if relationship_status.present?),
  (10 if language.present?),
  (10 if qualification.present?),
  ((counts = interests.count.to_i) >= 10 ? 10 : (counts * 5)),
].compact.sum
```

Comment: I like the technique but find the line dealing with "interests" discordant, even jarring. I'd find it more pleasing if that line were removed and the last line were replaced with `].compact.sum + interest_cost`, where `interest_cost` is a method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You may be right. But perhaps what should be improved is the logic design.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an instance method in your model:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   def percentage
      value = 0
      values = [[:date_of_birth, 15], [:gender, 15], [:relationship_status,10], [:language,10], [:qualification, 10]]
      values.each do |attr,val|
          value += val if self.send(attr).present?
      end
      value += self.interests.count >= 10 ? 10 : self.interests.count*5 if self.interests.present?
      # Rails should return the value of the last line, which is the "value" var
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use `@user.percentage`, where `@user` is your instance var for the model.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think that "less lines" is a good idea, but if you want your code in less lines, you can write it like this:

```
percentage = 0; if date_of_birth.present? then percentage += 15 end; if gender.present? then percentage += 15 end; if relationship_status.present? then percentage += 10 end; if language.present? then percentage += 10 end; if qualification.present? then percentage += 10 end; if interests.present? then if interests.count >= 10 then percentage += 10 else percentage += interests.count*5 end end
```

In Ruby, you can (almost) always replace linebreaks with semicolons to make your code fit on less lines. In fact, *every* Ruby program can *always* be written on a single line.

Comment: I agree that "less lines" is not a good idea. The grammatically correct "fewer lines" is no better. It grates whenever I see the sign "Less than 10 items" at a store's checkout lane.

Answer (score 0):

```
inc_att = ["date_of_birth", "gender", "relationship_status" , "language", "qualification", "interests"]

inc_att.each do |s|

  if self[s].present? && (s == "date_of_birth" || s == "gender")
      percentage += 15
  elsif self[s].present? && s == "interests" && self[s].count < 10
      percentage += self[s].count * 5
  else
      percentage += 10 if self[s].present?
  end

end
```

Have a look into it

Comment: One weakness of this approach is that you have to rewrite code substantially if any of the values to be summed are changed.

Comment: Ya it just suits for current requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
inc_att = ["date_of_birth", "gender", "relationship_status" , "language",   "qualification", "interests"]

inc_att.each do |s|

if self[s].present? && (s == "date_of_birth" || s == "gender")
  percentage += 15
elsif self[s].present? && s == "interests" && self[s].count < 10
  percentage += self[s].count * 5
else
  percentage += 10 if self[s].present?
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @sawa's answer:

```
counts = interests.count.to_i
percentage = (counts >= 10 ? 10 : (counts * 5)) + 
  [
    date_of_birth.present?       && 15,
    gender.present?              && 15,
    relationship_status.present? && 10,
    language.present?            && 10,
    qualification.present?       && 10,
  ].select(&:itself).sum
```